# Create an SQL Backup without administrator priveleges

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2014

I have a script that makes a backup of 3 sql databases.

I've attached the full script and its output in the two code blocks below. Don't be intimidated by their size, i'm simply calling the powershell cmdlet `Backup-SqlDatabase` at some point.

[Backup-SqlDatabase documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/backup-sqldatabase?view=sqlserver-ps)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/backup-sqldatabase?view=sqlserver-ps

```
sqlServerInstanceName = 'localhost\SQLEXPRESS2014' 
$sqlUserName = 'SomeName'
$sqlPassword = 'SomePassword'
$secureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $sqlPassword -AsPlainText -Force

...

    # Backing up Sql database
    #

    # SQL cmdlets below need some dll imports from system
    # These do not get loaded sometime when running under an non-admin account (Cannof find a provider with the name 'SqlServer')
    # Running this dummy command seems to load all needed dlls
    # Also see: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/unable-access-sql-provider-in-powershell-without-running-an-invoke-sqlcmd-first
    Invoke-Sqlcmd | Out-Null

    # To use any SQL cmdlets we need to create a ps virtual drive with the right authenitcation
    # See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/manage-authentication-in-database-engine-powershell?view=sql-server-ver15#sql-server-authentication-using-a-virtual-drive
    # NOTE the above docs are a bit confusing, this seemed to work: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f9901f20-01db-4d6e-bcfd-ecb5ca3ed64c/powershell-sqlserver-connect-via-newpsdrive?forum=winserverpowershell

    $sqlPsDrivename = 'sqlPsDrive'
    $sqlRoot = "SQLSERVER:\SQL\$sqlServerInstanceName"
    $sqlCred = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $sqlUserName,$secureString
    
    if (Test-Path "$($sqlPsDrivename):")
    {
        Remove-PSDrive $sqlPsDrivename -PSProvider SqlServer -Scope 1 
    }
    
    $null = New-PSDrive $sqlPsDrivename -PSProvider SqlServer -Root $sqlRoot -Credential $sqlCred -Scope 1  
    
    $null = Set-Location "$($sqlPsDrivename):"

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database[]] $allDatabases = Get-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $sqlServerInstanceName 
    $databases = $allDatabases | Where-Object {$_.IsSystemObject -eq $false}

    if($databases -eq $null)
    {
        throw "No non-system databases were found in $sqlServerInstanceName"
    }

    $null = [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory($sqlBackupDirectory)
    Write-Host Going to backup $databases.Count databases to $sqlBackupDirectory
    
    $databases | Backup-SqlDatabase -BackupContainer $sqlBackupDirectory -Verbose

    Write-Host Done with backing up $databases.Count databases to $sqlBackupDirectory
```

This seems to work as it should, however it only works when I run this under windows account `Administrator`. However when I run this under a regular user account e.g. `Operator` this fails with the following **script output**:

```
Going to backup 3 databases to C:\ITM\FullBackup\Temp\Database
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Backup-SqlDatabase" on target "[localhost\SQLEXPRESS2014]".
VERBOSE: 
        declare @HkeyLocal nvarchar(18)
        declare @ServicesRegPath nvarchar(34)
        declare @SqlServiceRegPath sysname
        declare @BrowserServiceRegPath sysname
        declare @MSSqlServerRegPath nvarchar(31)
        declare @InstanceNamesRegPath nvarchar(59)
        declare @InstanceRegPath sysname
        declare @SetupRegPath sysname
        declare @NpRegPath sysname
        declare @TcpRegPath sysname
        declare @RegPathParams sysname
        declare @FilestreamRegPath sysname

        select @HkeyLocal=N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'

        -- Instance-based paths
        select @MSSqlServerRegPath=N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer'
        select @InstanceRegPath=@MSSqlServerRegPath + N'\MSSQLServer'
        select @FilestreamRegPath=@InstanceRegPath + N'\Filestream'
        select @SetupRegPath=@MSSqlServerRegPath + N'\Setup'
        select @RegPathParams=@InstanceRegPath+'\Parameters'

        -- Services
        select @ServicesRegPath=N'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services'
        select @SqlServiceRegPath=@ServicesRegPath + N'\MSSQLSERVER'
        select @BrowserServiceRegPath=@ServicesRegPath + N'\SQLBrowser'

        -- InstanceId setting
        select @InstanceNamesRegPath=N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL'

        -- Network settings
        select @NpRegPath=@InstanceRegPath + N'\SuperSocketNetLib\Np'
        select @TcpRegPath=@InstanceRegPath + N'\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp'
      


        declare @SmoAuditLevel int
        exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread @HkeyLocal, @InstanceRegPath, N'AuditLevel', @SmoAuditLevel OUTPUT
      


        declare @NumErrorLogs int
        exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread @HkeyLocal, @InstanceRegPath, N'NumErrorLogs', @NumErrorLogs OUTPUT
      


        declare @SmoLoginMode int
        exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread @HkeyLocal, @InstanceRegPath, N'LoginMode', @SmoLoginMode OUTPUT
      


        declare @SmoMailProfile nvarchar(512)
        exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread @HkeyLocal, @InstanceRegPath, N'MailAccountName', @SmoMailProfile OUTPUT
      


        declare @BackupDirectory nvarchar(512)
        if 1=isnull(cast(SERVERPROPERTY('IsLocalDB') as bit), 0)
          select @BackupDirectory=cast(SERVERPROPERTY('instancedefaultdatapath') as nvarchar(512))
        else
          exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread @HkeyLocal, @InstanceRegPath, N'BackupDirectory', @BackupDirectory OUTPUT
      


        declare @SmoPerfMonMode int
        exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread @HkeyLocal, @InstanceRegPath, N'Performance', @SmoPerfMonMode OUTPUT

        if @SmoPerfMonMode is null
        begin
        set @SmoPerfMonMode = 1000
        end
      


        declare @InstallSqlDataDir nvarchar(512)
        exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread @HkeyLocal, @SetupRegPath, N'SQLDataRoot', @InstallSqlDataDir OUTPUT
      


        declare @MasterPath nvarchar(512)
        declare @LogPath nvarchar(512)
        declare @ErrorLog nvarchar(512)
        declare @ErrorLogPath nvarchar(512)

        select @MasterPath=substring(physical_name, 1, len(physical_name) - charindex('\', reverse(physical_name))) from master.sys.database_files where name=N'master'
        select @LogPath=substring(physical_name, 1, len(physical_name) - charindex('\', reverse(physical_name))) from master.sys.database_files where name=N'mastlog'
        select @ErrorLog=cast(SERVERPROPERTY(N'errorlogfilename') as nvarchar(512))
        select @ErrorLogPath=substring(@ErrorLog, 1, len(@ErrorLog) - charindex('\', reverse(@ErrorLog)))
      


        declare @SmoRoot nvarchar(512)
        exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread @HkeyLocal, @SetupRegPath, N'SQLPath', @SmoRoot OUTPUT
      


        declare @ServiceStartMode int
        EXEC master.sys.xp_instance_regread @HkeyLocal, @SqlServiceRegPath, N'Start', @ServiceStartMode OUTPUT
      


        declare @ServiceAccount nvarchar(512)
        EXEC master.sys.xp_instance_regread @HkeyLocal, @SqlServiceRegPath, N'ObjectName', @ServiceAccount OUTPUT
      


        declare @NamedPipesEnabled int
        exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread @HkeyLocal, @NpRegPath, N'Enabled', @NamedPipesEnabled OUTPUT
      


        declare @TcpEnabled int
        EXEC master.sys.xp_instance_regread @HkeyLocal, @TcpRegPath, N'Enabled', @TcpEnabled OUTPUT
      


        declare @InstallSharedDirectory nvarchar(512)
        EXEC master.sys.xp_instance_regread @HkeyLocal, @SetupRegPath, N'SQLPath', @InstallSharedDirectory OUTPUT
      


        declare @SqlGroup nvarchar(512)
        exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread @HkeyLocal, @SetupRegPath, N'SQLGroup', @SqlGroup OUTPUT
      


        declare @FilestreamLevel int
        exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread @HkeyLocal, @FilestreamRegPath, N'EnableLevel', @FilestreamLevel OUTPUT
      


        declare @FilestreamShareName nvarchar(512)
        exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread @HkeyLocal, @FilestreamRegPath, N'ShareName', @FilestreamShareName OUTPUT
      


        declare @cluster_name nvarchar(128)
        declare @quorum_type tinyint
        declare @quorum_state tinyint
        BEGIN TRY
            SELECT @cluster_name = cluster_name, 
                @quorum_type = quorum_type,
                @quorum_state = quorum_state
            FROM sys.dm_hadr_cluster
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF(ERROR_NUMBER() NOT IN (297,300))
            BEGIN
                THROW
            END
        END CATCH
      

SELECT
@SmoAuditLevel AS [AuditLevel],
ISNULL(@NumErrorLogs, -1) AS [NumberOfLogFiles],
(case when @SmoLoginMode < 3 then @SmoLoginMode else 9 end) AS [LoginMode],
ISNULL(@SmoMailProfile,N'') AS [MailProfile],
@BackupDirectory AS [BackupDirectory],
@SmoPerfMonMode AS [PerfMonMode],
ISNULL(@InstallSqlDataDir,N'') AS [InstallDataDirectory],
CAST(@@SERVICENAME AS sysname) AS [ServiceName],
@ErrorLogPath AS [ErrorLogPath],
@SmoRoot AS [RootDirectory],
CAST(case when 'a' <> 'A' then 1 else 0 end AS bit) AS [IsCaseSensitive],
@@MAX_PRECISION AS [MaxPrecision],
CAST(FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled') AS bit) AS [IsFullTextInstalled],
SERVERPROPERTY(N'ProductVersion') AS [VersionString],
CAST(SERVERPROPERTY(N'Edition') AS sysname) AS [Edition],
CAST(SERVERPROPERTY(N'ProductLevel') AS sysname) AS [ProductLevel],
CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('IsSingleUser') AS bit) AS [IsSingleUser],
CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') AS int) AS [EngineEdition],
convert(sysname, serverproperty(N'collation')) AS [Collation],
CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('IsClustered') AS bit) AS [IsClustered],
CAST(SERVERPROPERTY(N'MachineName') AS sysname) AS [NetName],
@LogPath AS [MasterDBLogPath],
@MasterPath AS [MasterDBPath],
SERVERPROPERTY('instancedefaultdatapath') AS [DefaultFile],
SERVERPROPERTY('instancedefaultlogpath') AS [DefaultLog],
SERVERPROPERTY(N'ResourceVersion') AS [ResourceVersionString],
SERVERPROPERTY(N'ResourceLastUpdateDateTime') AS [ResourceLastUpdateDateTime],
SERVERPROPERTY(N'CollationID') AS [CollationID],
SERVERPROPERTY(N'ComparisonStyle') AS [ComparisonStyle],
SERVERPROPERTY(N'SqlCharSet') AS [SqlCharSet],
SERVERPROPERTY(N'SqlCharSetName') AS [SqlCharSetName],
SERVERPROPERTY(N'SqlSortOrder') AS [SqlSortOrder],
SERVERPROPERTY(N'SqlSortOrderName') AS [SqlSortOrderName],
SERVERPROPERTY(N'ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS') AS [ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS],
SERVERPROPERTY(N'BuildClrVersion') AS [BuildClrVersionString],
@ServiceStartMode AS [ServiceStartMode],
ISNULL(@ServiceAccount,N'') AS [ServiceAccount],
CAST(@NamedPipesEnabled AS bit) AS [NamedPipesEnabled],
CAST(@TcpEnabled AS bit) AS [TcpEnabled],
ISNULL(@InstallSharedDirectory,N'') AS [InstallSharedDirectory],
ISNULL(suser_sname(sid_binary(ISNULL(@SqlGroup,N''))),N'') AS [SqlDomainGroup],
case when 1=msdb.dbo.fn_syspolicy_is_automation_enabled() and exists (select * from msdb.dbo.syspolicy_system_health_state  where target_query_expression_with_id like 'Server%' ) then 1 else 
0 end AS [PolicyHealthState],
@FilestreamLevel AS [FilestreamLevel],
ISNULL(@FilestreamShareName,N'') AS [FilestreamShareName],
-1 AS [TapeLoadWaitTime],
CAST(SERVERPROPERTY(N'IsHadrEnabled') AS bit) AS [IsHadrEnabled],
SERVERPROPERTY(N'HADRManagerStatus') AS [HadrManagerStatus],
ISNULL(@cluster_name, '') AS [ClusterName],
ISNULL(@quorum_type, 4) AS [ClusterQuorumType],
ISNULL(@quorum_state, 3) AS [ClusterQuorumState],
SUSER_SID(@ServiceAccount, 0) AS [ServiceAccountSid],
CAST(
        serverproperty(N'Servername')
       AS sysname) AS [Name],
CAST(
        ISNULL(serverproperty(N'instancename'),N'')
       AS sysname) AS [InstanceName],
CAST(0x0001 AS int) AS [Status],
0 AS [IsContainedAuthentication],
CAST(null AS int) AS [ServerType]
VERBOSE: RegQueryValueEx() returned error 2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.'
VERBOSE: RegQueryValueEx() returned error 2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.'
VERBOSE: 
        declare @HkeyLocal nvarchar(18)
        declare @ServicesRegPath nvarchar(34)
        declare @SqlServiceRegPath sysname
        declare @BrowserServiceRegPath sysname
        declare @MSSqlServerRegPath nvarchar(31)
        declare @InstanceNamesRegPath nvarchar(59)
        declare @InstanceRegPath sysname
        declare @SetupRegPath sysname
        declare @NpRegPath sysname
        declare @TcpRegPath sysname
        declare @RegPathParams sysname
        declare @FilestreamRegPath sysname

        select @HkeyLocal=N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'

        -- Instance-based paths
        select @MSSqlServerRegPath=N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer'
        select @InstanceRegPath=@MSSqlServerRegPath + N'\MSSQLServer'
        select @FilestreamRegPath=@InstanceRegPath + N'\Filestream'
        select @SetupRegPath=@MSSqlServerRegPath + N'\Setup'
        select @RegPathParams=@InstanceRegPath+'\Parameters'

        -- Services
        select @ServicesRegPath=N'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services'
        select @SqlServiceRegPath=@ServicesRegPath + N'\MSSQLSERVER'
        select @BrowserServiceRegPath=@ServicesRegPath + N'\SQLBrowser'

        -- InstanceId setting
        select @InstanceNamesRegPath=N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL'

        -- Network settings
        select @NpRegPath=@InstanceRegPath + N'\SuperSocketNetLib\Np'
        select @TcpRegPath=@InstanceRegPath + N'\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp'
      


        declare @ServiceInstanceId nvarchar(512)
        EXEC master.sys.xp_regread @HkeyLocal, @InstanceNamesRegPath, @@SERVICENAME, @ServiceInstanceId OUTPUT
      

SELECT
ISNULL(@ServiceInstanceId,N'') AS [ServiceInstanceId]
D:\Projects\Hmi.Ushape\DistributedFiles\FullBackup\FullBackup.ps1 : An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,FullBackup.ps1
 
Script end.
```

In both cases, I connect with a SQL server account - not a windows account. This account has DBO rights for the 3 databases - so in my mind it should be able to always create a backup.

In the verbose logging of the `Backup-SqlDatabase` command you can see:
`VERBOSE: RegQueryValueEx() returned error 2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.'`. I also see that apparently it tries to read from `HKLM` which of course is only accessible under an administrator account, and maybe even elevation.

Is there another way for me to create a backup (or copy the .mdf/.ldf files, without sql locking the files) where I don't have to run under an administrator account? I only have an sql account with ownership to those 3 databases, and a user windows account.

Comment: The question has a lot of code, which makes debugging hard. Try to create an [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); that likely helps you to find out which part of the code doesn't work in the first place.

Comment: @vonPryz Hiya, the second part is just debug output. I tried putting it in a spoiler (`<summary>`) but that did not work, other than that - the script already is the minimal reproducible sample.

Comment: You're using a lot of undocumented extended procedures there. Who knows what their requirements are? Purely from a backups point of view the SQL Login/account performing the backup needs the db_backupoperator role and the destination folder for the backups requires modify permissions for the account under which SQL Server itself is executing.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Hello! thanks for reviewing my Q. I'm not sure what you mean with 'undocumented extended procedures' I'm simply calling the powershell cmdlet `Backup-SqlDatabase` which seems well documented; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/backup-sqldatabase?view=sqlserver-ps Regarding permissions, As far as i'm aware `db_owner` also inherits `db_backupoperator` permissions. The sql account is an owner - so that should work. Note, this works when i run it as a windows user in the `Administrator` group. But not without that group.

Comment: TBH I'm not an sql expert, I just need a way to create a backup of the user databases in the server, for which i have an account with `db_owner`. But i must be able to do this with a regular, non-administrator, windows user account (e.g. `Operator`). Preferably i'd like to do this via powershell. Powershell also allows me to run plain SQL. Anyhow - is there more information i could provide?

Comment: Although the end requirement might be to backup a database, the verbose output is doing all kinds of privileged things that are not necessary for backing up a database, like reading the registry with `xp_instance_regread ` . I don't know how that powershell command results in all that output. Maybe that's normal for `Backup-SqlDatabase`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Hello, thanks for pitching in! Right, I understand what you're saying now. But indeed - I was also amazed at these queries and i couldn't really find out what they're fore. I tried some other params to the cmdlet but that was no use either, the problem persisted. There's already an answer that involves calling plain sql and i'll think i'll go that route and drop the powershell command.

Comment: 100% use the SQL approach. It looks like those registry reads are trying to work out the default backup directory but there's a whole load of other operations in there that have no relevance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer would not explain how to use the `Backup-SqlDatabase` in PowerShell, nor how to configure permissions needed to run this cmdlet.

When I wanted to backup a database with a PowerShell script I did not use the `Backup-SqlDatabase` cmdlet. I prefer to compose a native SQL `BACKUP DATABASE` command.

So, I created two files. One was a PowerShell script, another was a SQL script.

`make_backup.sql` has a `BACKUP DATABASE` command:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [DBName] TO DISK = N'D:\BACKUP\DBNameFull.bak' WITH 
    FORMAT, INIT, NAME = N'DBName-Full Database Backup', 
    SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION, CHECKSUM
```

Adjust the options as needed.

`make_backup.ps1` executes the SQL script using `sqlcmd`:

```
& sqlcmd -S DBName -U UserName -P UserPassword -i "make_backup.sql"
```

Comment: Hiya Vladimir, Thanks for posting an answer. I'm going to try to run this and see if that works better. Just some followup questions: a) have you seen this work under a regular, non-administrator windows user account before? and b) could you provide some indication about why you used these options? why are they handy/necesary? I'll be sure to check the docs for those options in a minute.

Comment: @sommmen, yes, I run this PowerShell script under the normal user. Both manually and via the Task Scheduler. This user has full rights to the folder where the backup goes. Options for `BACKUP DATABASE`? I used SSMS to generate a script (when you use SSMS GUI to manually backup a database there is a button "generate script"). I took it as a starting point and adjusted to my liking.

Comment: Tested this approach and it worked as it should. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer, I dropped usage of `Backup-SqlDatabase` and i edited my script as follows:

BackupDatabase.sql

```sql
BACKUP DATABASE [$(dbName)] TO DISK = N'$(filePath)' WITH 
    FORMAT, INIT, NAME = N'$(dbName)-Full Database Backup', 
    SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, CHECKSUM
```

FullBackup.ps1

```
function Backup-SingleDatabase
{
    Param(

        [string] $dbName,
        [string] $filePath

    )
        
    Write-Host Backing up $dbName to $filePath

    $SqlcmdVariables= @(
        "dbName=$dbName",
        "filePath=$filePath"
    )

    Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $BackupDatabaseSqlFilePath -Database $dbName -Variable $SqlcmdVariables -OutputSqlErrors $true -SuppressProviderContextWarning
}

...

# Backing up Sql database
#

# SQL cmdlets below need some dll imports from system
# These do not get loaded sometime when running under an non-admin account (Cannof find a provider with the name 'SqlServer')
# Running this dummy command seems to load all needed dlls
# Also see: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/unable-access-sql-provider-in-powershell-without-running-an-invoke-sqlcmd-first
Invoke-Sqlcmd | Out-Null

# To use any SQL cmdlets we need to create a ps virtual drive with the right authenitcation
# See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/manage-authentication-in-database-engine-powershell?view=sql-server-ver15#sql-server-authentication-using-a-virtual-drive
# NOTE the above docs are a bit confusing, this seemed to work: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f9901f20-01db-4d6e-bcfd-ecb5ca3ed64c/powershell-sqlserver-connect-via-newpsdrive?forum=winserverpowershell

$sqlPsDrivename = 'sqlPsDrive'
$sqlRoot = "SQLSERVER:\SQL\$sqlServerInstanceName"
$secureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $sqlPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$sqlCred = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $sqlUserName,$secureString

if (Test-Path "$($sqlPsDrivename):")
{
    Remove-PSDrive $sqlPsDrivename -PSProvider SqlServer -Scope 1 
}

$null = New-PSDrive $sqlPsDrivename -PSProvider SqlServer -Root $sqlRoot -Credential $sqlCred -Scope 1  

$null = Set-Location "$($sqlPsDrivename):"

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database[]] $allDatabases = Get-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $sqlServerInstanceName 
$databases_ = $allDatabases | Where-Object {$_.IsSystemObject -eq $false}

if($databases_ -eq $null)
{
    throw "No non-system databases were found in $sqlServerInstanceName"
}

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database[]] $databases = $databases_

$null = [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory($sqlBackupDirectory)
Write-Host Going to backup $databases.Count databases to $sqlBackupDirectory

$databases | % {Backup-SingleDatabase -dbName "$($_.Name)" -filePath "$sqlBackupDirectory\$($_.Name)_$($hostName)_$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd-HHmmss).bak"}

# Cleaning up after we're done
Pop-Location
```

The following article helped with passing arguments to the sql script:
https://www.dbbest.com/blog/using-powershell-invoke-sqlcmd-with-variable/

If I were to redo this, I would probably put all logic in the `.sql` file and call that instead. Now I have some logic in the .ps1 file regarding fetching all user databases in the server, and then I call my `.sql` script for each database. I can't be bothered with rewriting that at this point though.

Comment: Great answer but few instructions on how to specify database name and user credentials